# Display logged in user spring security

Tags: spring, spring-security, thymeleaf

I have this in my index.

```
<div sec:authorize="isAuthenticated()">
    <p>Logged user: <span sec:authentication="name"></span></p>
</div>
```

It displays "Logged user:" and nothing else even when no user is logged in. User is definitely logging in correctly. The intention is to have it say "Logged user:myusername" when I am logged it and nothing when I am not.
I have this bean in a `@Configuration` class

```
@Bean
public SpringSecurityDialect securityDialect() {
    return new SpringSecurityDialect();
}
```

My build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories{
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.5.2.RELEASE'
    }
}


apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'idea'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

// Specify dependencies
dependencies {

    compile 'org.hashids:hashids:1.0.1'
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf'
    compile 'org.springframework:spring-orm:4.3.7.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.2.9.Final'
    compile 'org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:5.0.6.Final'
    compile 'org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-dbcp:8.0.30'
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
    compile 'org.thymeleaf.extras:thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4:2.1.2.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.data', name: 'spring-data-jpa', version: '1.11.1.RELEASE'
    runtime 'com.h2database:h2'
    runtime 'javax.transaction:jta:1.1'
    runtime 'org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:1.8.7'
    testCompile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}
```

My html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"></meta>
    <title>Homepage</title>
</head>
<body>
<div sec:authorize="isAuthenticated()">
    <p>Logged user: <span sec:authentication="name"></span></p>
</div>
<form action="searchProducts" method="get">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td> What you want to search for :</td>
            <td>
                <input name="searchterm" type="text"/>
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="search"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Thymeleaf config

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.thymeleaf.extras.springsecurity4.dialect.SpringSecurityDialect;

@Configuration
public class ThymeleafConfig {

    @Bean
    public SpringSecurityDialect springSecurityDialect() {
        return new SpringSecurityDialect();
    }
}
```

Template config

```
@Configuration
public class TemplateConfig {

    @Bean
    public SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver() {
        final SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
        templateResolver.setCacheable(false);
        templateResolver.setPrefix("classpath:/");
        templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
        return templateResolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine() {
        final SpringTemplateEngine springTemplateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
        springTemplateEngine.addTemplateResolver(templateResolver());
        return springTemplateEngine;
    }

    @Bean
    public ThymeleafViewResolver viewResolver() {
        final ThymeleafViewResolver viewResolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine());
        viewResolver.setOrder(1);
        return viewResolver;
    }
}
```

Security config

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userService);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your html, you have to add the security namespace :

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
  xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity3">
```

**Update :**

Daniel also added `springTemplateEngine.addDialect(new SpringSecurityDialect());` to `templateEngine()`

Comment: With that to work off I added the line springTemplateEngine.addDialect(new SpringSecurityDialect()); to templateEngine() and it fixed it thanks alot